# Grouping a collection with the related objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a group of `task`s where a task may be linked to another one via the `runs_with` field as shown below.

```
<Task id: 'abc', name: 'paint the fance', progressive: 1, runs_with: nil>
<Task id: 'def', name: 'mow the lawn', progressive: 2, runs_with: 1>
<Task id: 'ghi', name: 'wash the dishes', progressive: 3, runs_with: nil>
<Task id: 'xyz', name: 'take out the trash', progressive: 4, runs_with: 3>
<Task id: 'qur', name: 'wash the car', progressive: 5, runs_with: 2>
<Task id: 'gbj', name: 'walk the dog', progressive: 6, runs_with: 3>
```

Now I need to group them so all the linked ones end up in a group (an array).

```
[[<Task id: 'abc', name: 'paint the fance', progressive: 1, runs_with: nil>,
  <Task id: 'def', name: 'mow the lawn', progressive: 2, runs_with: 1>,
  <Task id: 'qur', name: 'wash the car', progressive: 5, runs_with: 2>],
 [<Task id: 'ghi', name: 'wash the dishes', progressive: 3, runs_with: nil>,
  <Task id: 'xyz', name: 'take out the trash', progressive: 4, runs_with: 3>,
  <Task id: 'gbj', name: 'walk the dog', progressive: 6, runs_with: 3>]]
```

My initial idea is to

> - partition on `runs_with`.
> - create a group for each `task` that can run alone.
> - loop through the other `task`s and append them to the group including the linked `task`.

Wondering if there is any more idiomatic way to group them.

Comment: Does `runs_with` refer to the number in `progressive`?

Comment: Yes, it does. My bad I didn’t specify it before. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I would approach it. Given a `Task` class and an array of tasks:

```
class Task
  ATTRIBUTES = [:id, :name, :progressive, :runs_with]
  attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def inspect
    '<Task %s>' % ATTRIBUTES.map { |a| '%s: %s' % [a, send(a).inspect] }.join(', ')
  end
end

tasks = [
  Task.new(id: 'abc', name: 'paint the fance', progressive: 1, runs_with: nil),
  Task.new(id: 'def', name: 'mow the lawn', progressive: 2, runs_with: 1),
  Task.new(id: 'ghi', name: 'wash the dishes', progressive: 3, runs_with: nil),
  Task.new(id: 'xyz', name: 'take out the trash', progressive: 4, runs_with: 3),
  Task.new(id: 'qur', name: 'wash the car', progressive: 5, runs_with: 2),
  Task.new(id: 'gbj', name: 'walk the dog', progressive: 6, runs_with: 3)
]
```

I would create a hash where each value would be the task wrapped in an array with its number as the key:

```
hash = tasks.group_by(&:progressive)

{
  1 => [<Task id: "abc", name: "paint the fance", progressive: 1, runs_with: nil>],
  2 => [<Task id: "def", name: "mow the lawn", progressive: 2, runs_with: 1>],
  3 => [<Task id: "ghi", name: "wash the dishes", progressive: 3, runs_with: nil>],
  4 => [<Task id: "xyz", name: "take out the trash", progressive: 4, runs_with: 3>],
  5 => [<Task id: "qur", name: "wash the car", progressive: 5, runs_with: 2>],
  6 => [<Task id: "gbj", name: "walk the dog", progressive: 6, runs_with: 3>]
}
```

Then I would traverse the original `tasks` array and for each task with a `runs_with` attribute, merge the task's array with the corresponding task's array into one:

```
tasks.each do |task|
  if task.runs_with
    hash[task.runs_with].concat(hash[task.progressive])
    hash[task.progressive] = hash[task.runs_with]
  end
end
```

This will effectively merge the arrays and reduce the number of arrays along the way. The hash however will refer to those (identical) arrays from different keys, so in the end we have to fetch the hash's *unique* values:

```
hash.values.uniq
#=> [[<Task id: "abc", name: "paint the fance", progressive: 1, runs_with: nil>,
#     <Task id: "def", name: "mow the lawn", progressive: 2, runs_with: 1>,
#     <Task id: "qur", name: "wash the car", progressive: 5, runs_with: 2>],
#    [<Task id: "ghi", name: "wash the dishes", progressive: 3, runs_with: nil>,
#     <Task id: "xyz", name: "take out the trash", progressive: 4, runs_with: 3>,
#     <Task id: "gbj", name: "walk the dog", progressive: 6, runs_with: 3>]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It simplifies the grouping compared to my initial idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
tasks.group_by(&:runs_with).values
```

should do it.

Basically the `groups_by` method will create a hash where the runs_with value is the key and the value is an array of all the tasks with that runs_with value. Then you simple call `values` on the hash to get an array of all values.

Comment: The OP's structure is more like a linked list, e.g. 1, 2, and 5 are grouped because 5 runs with 2, and 2 runs with 1. All three have different `run_with` values, though.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose:

```
tasks = [
  { Task id: 'abc', progressive: 1, runs_with: nil },
  { Task id: 'def', progressive: 2, runs_with: 1 },
  { Task id: 'ghi', progressive: 3, runs_with: nil },
  { Task id: 'xyz', progressive: 4, runs_with: 3 },
  { Task id: 'qur', progressive: 5, runs_with: 2 },
  { Task id: 'gbj', progressive: 6, runs_with: 3 }
]
```

which is effectively the same problem.

You could first partition the array as follows:

```
heads, tails = tasks.partition { |h| h[:runs_with].nil? }
  #=> [[{:Task_id=>"abc", :progressive=>1, :runs_with=>nil},
  #     {:Task_id=>"ghi", :progressive=>3, :runs_with=>nil}],
  #    [{:Task_id=>"def", :progressive=>2, :runs_with=>1},
  #     {:Task_id=>"xyz", :progressive=>4, :runs_with=>3},
  #     {:Task_id=>"qur", :progressive=>5, :runs_with=>2},
  #     {:Task_id=>"gbj", :progressive=>6, :runs_with=>3}]]
```

so that

```
heads
  #=> [{:Task_id=>"abc", :progressive=>1, :runs_with=>nil},
  #    {:Task_id=>"ghi", :progressive=>3, :runs_with=>nil}]
tails
  #=> [{:Task_id=>"def", :progressive=>2, :runs_with=>1},
  #    {:Task_id=>"xyz", :progressive=>4, :runs_with=>3},
  #    {:Task_id=>"qur", :progressive=>5, :runs_with=>2},
  #    {:Task_id=>"gbj", :progressive=>6, :runs_with=>3}]
```

Next define an the array of arrays which, after appending hashes to its elements, is to be returned:

```
head_groups = heads.map { |head| [head] }
  #=>[[{:Task_id=>"abc", :progressive=>1, :runs_with=>nil}],
  #   [{:Task_id=>"ghi", :progressive=>3, :runs_with=>nil}]]
```

We will need to keep track of the value of `:progressive` for the last element (a hash) for each element (an array) of `head_groups`):

```
curr_progressive = heads.each_index.with_object({}) {|i,h| h[heads[i] [:progressive]] = i}
  #=> {1=>0, 3=>1}
```

Now sort the tails by `tail[:runs_with]`:

```
sorted_tails = tails.sort_by { |tail| tail[:runs_with] }
  #=> [{:Task_id=>"def", :progressive=>2, :runs_with=>1},
  #    {:Task_id=>"qur", :progressive=>5, :runs_with=>2},
  #    {:Task_id=>"xyz", :progressive=>4, :runs_with=>3},
  #    {:Task_id=>"gbj", :progressive=>6, :runs_with=>3}]
```

We now need only append each of the hashes in `sorted_tails` to the appropriate element (array) of `head_groups`:

```
sorted_tails.each_with_object(head_groups) do |tail, head_groups|
  head_group = curr_progressive[tail[:runs_with]]
  head_groups[head_group] << tail
  curr_progressive[tail[:progressive]] = head_group
end
  #=>[[{:Task_id=>"abc", :progressive=>1, :runs_with=>nil},
  #    {:Task_id=>"def", :progressive=>2, :runs_with=>1},
  #    {:Task_id=>"qur", :progressive=>5, :runs_with=>2}],
  #   [{:Task_id=>"ghi", :progressive=>3, :runs_with=>nil},
  #    {:Task_id=>"xyz", :progressive=>4, :runs_with=>3},
  #    {:Task_id=>"gbj", :progressive=>6, :runs_with=>3}]]
```

---

We could of course simply these steps somewhat. After computing `heads`, `tails` and `curr_progressive` we could write the following:

```
tails.sort_by { |tail| tail[:runs_with] }
     .each_with_object(heads.map { |head| [head] }) do |tail, head_groups|
        head_group = curr_progressive[tail[:runs_with]]
        head_groups[head_group] << tail
        curr_progressive[tail[:progressive]] = head_group
      end
```

---

I would like to mention that in preparing this answer I used (for the first time) a [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org) with [Ruby v2.7.1 installed](https://github.com/SciRuby/iruby) to write and test code. Jupyter Notebooks are popular for running Python code, but they can be used with many other languages as well. [Here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/RubyData/binder/master?filepath=ruby-data.ipynb) is an example of their use with Ruby. I'm impressed.